# Acccessing a network service attached only to localhost via LAN - Windows 11

Tags: networking

Is there a way to get connectivity to a network service that is accessible only via localhost from a LAN IP under Windows 11?

I'm trying to access a docker image hosted on Windows over LAN. So far I've only managed to get access via `localhost:xxxx`

`--net=host` : doen't seem to open a port on either localhost or the LAN IP, `-p xxxx:xxxx`: opens a port on localhost only

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How are you using Docker? Are you specifying the port mapping correctly? No tricks are required for Docker, except of course setting up the firewall.

Comment: You cannot port forward to local host, because local host means, the local adapter on that interface. For windows 11, that means it is redirected to windows 11, and on docker it means, the traffic inside docker is redirected to itself. You will have to redirect to the LAN IP of the other instance. Always.

Comment: @DanielB I've tried a couple of network configurations with docker: `--net=host` : doen't seem to open a port on either localhost or the LAN IP, and `-p xxxx:xxxx`: which opens a port on localhost only.

Comment: @LPChip perhaps I'm not using the correct term. On macOS I've used software that acts as a proxy in a similar situation.

Comment: `--net=host` is not possible on Windows and should not generally be used anyway. // Again: How are you using Docker? Docker Desktop? Self-installed Docker in WSL 2 or some other VM?

Comment: Localhost gives access to the network card that is present on that OS, with ip address: 127.0.0.1. Lets say, your Win11 has ip adress: 192.168.1.1 and docker has 192.168.1.44. On Win 11, localhost will be 127.0.0.1, redirecting to 192.168.1.1, but you want to open a port to 192.168.1.44. So if your docker with .44 can only be accessed through localhost, it means its access is shielded and it needs to be configured to allow more than just localhost, as it needs access from 1.1 too.

Comment: @DanielB Docker Desktop. Yeah, I read --net=host won't work under Windows. I have not read that it shouldn't generally be used before.

Comment: @LPChip yep. In terms of using only routing, localhost won't be accessible over LAN. Afaik the tool I used on macOS was acting as a proxy between the LAN IP address and 127.0.0.1, not routing the traffic.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question, No. Ports listening or otherwise established on the loopback interface cannot be accessed from another system. This is by design, and were it to not be the case, the security vulnerability that would result would be catastrophic.

Localhost only ports are commonly used for [Inter-Process Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) and services that should only be accessible locally.

In order to make your port accessible to the LAN, you must reconfigure the service to listen on an interface with a valid LAN IP or 0.0.0.0. The specific methods to do this vary by product, so you will have to consult the documentation for your product.

It is possible to write some kind of [Application Layer Gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-level_gateway) that you could deploy on the host bound to a LAN interface, and proxy communications to a localhost port, but this will require a knowledge of network programming and the command syntax used by the application, which are not commonly available to system administrators.